# Updating OpenGL on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opengl

When trying to run Portal 2, I recive this error:

```
SDL video target is 'x11'
SDL video target is 'x11'

SDL failed to create GL compatibility profile (whichProfile=0!
SDL failed to create GL compatibility profile (whichProfile=0!

PROBLEM: You appear to have OpenGL 1.4.0, but we need at least 2.0.0!
Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.
Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.
```

How do I update OpenGL so I can run Portal 2?

Answer (score 1):

They seem to discuss the issue in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/portal2/issues/235) as well as [this one](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3273). This issue seems to not be an OpenGL upgrade problem but rather, a problem with `libstdc++.so.6` located in `SteamApps/common/Portal 2/bin/libstdc++.so.6`. The solution posted by “xandark” seems to be the best suited solution to the issue:

1. Delete `SteamApps/common/Portal 2/bin/libstdc++.so.6`
2. Run the Steam client
3. `cd "SteamApps/common/Portal 2"`
4. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bin ./portal2_linux -game portal2 -windowed`

I thing that just doing step 1 and then running the Steam client will solve the issue. But please be sure to read those threads to get more info.

Comment: It's still giving the same error